# RingtonePreference is always null :(

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="Notifications">
    <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="vibration"
            android:title="Vibrate" 
            android:summary="Vibrate phone for notifications" />
    <CheckBoxPreference 
            android:key="play_tone"
            android:title="Play Ringtone" 
            android:summary="Play Ringtone for notifications" />
    <RingtonePreference
            android:key="app_ringtone"
            android:dependency="play_tone"
            android:title="Select Ringtone"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:shouldDisableView="true"
            android:summary="Pick a Ringtone" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

This is my preference xml. But,

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.getString("app_ringtone", null);
```

always returns null. I am debugging on a device (HTC Wildfire).

Comment: How do you know it's null? Just on the debugger or are you actually force closing? If so, show us a stack trace. Are you getting the NPE on getDefaultSharedPreferences or prefs.getString?

Comment: Look at the prefs.getString("app_ringtone", null) call I've made.

Comment: I have found out from the **SharedPreferences.getAll().keySet()** that "app_ringtone" key is not there at the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a sample project](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Prefs/Dialogs/) demonstrating collecting preferences, including ringtones. If this does not work on your device, then there may be a compatibility problem with the device.

Comment: This example works perfectly. But when I do the same with my application the ringtone gets reset to "Silent".

Comment: CommonsWare, please check the new answer I have posted below and offer solution if you can figure out the actual problem.

Answer (score 3):

In my case problem was that I overrided onActivityResult in PreferenceActivity and didn't invoke  super.onActivityResult(...).
Now it works fine:

```
public synchronized void onActivityResult(final int requestCode,
    int resultCode, final Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problematic XML:**

```
<activity android:name="Activity1" 
    android:label="Activity 1"/>
<activity android:name="Activity2" 
    android:label="Activity 2" />
<activity android:name="Settings"  
    android:label="Settings" />
```

I changed the **android:name="Activity1"** to **android:name=".Activity1"** FOR ALL ACTIVITIES and the code started working. The code also malfunctions if the **android:showSilent="false"** attribute is included in the **RingtonePreference** may be this is a bug. I figured this out after a lot of trial and errors. Any ideas, pls enlighten @Commonsware.

**Working XML:**

```
<activity android:name=".Activity1" 
    android:label="Activity 1"/>
<activity android:name=".Activity2" 
    android:label="Activity 2" />
<activity android:name=".Settings"  
    android:label="Settings" />
```